# Jersey: MultiPart form file upload Unsupported Media Type (415)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I'm having some trouble making a Jersey file upload service.

The spec is this: the server allows a client to access files using `GET` method. The `index.html`allows the user to `POST` multiple files using a multipart form data handler.

However, when I try to upload a CSV file (`Content-Type: text/csv`) the server instantly replies with a 415 error, neither entering my handler method code nor spitting out some error.

Here is my code:

```
@Path("/ui/")
public class HtmlServer {
    static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HtmlServer.class.getCanonicalName());

    @GET
    @Path("/{file}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response request(@PathParam("file") @DefaultValue("index.html") String path) {
        LOGGER.info("HTTP GET /ui/" + path);

        String data;
        try {
            if ("".equals(path))
                data = getFileBytes("web/index.html");
            else
                data = getFileBytes("web/" + path);
            return Response.ok(data, MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.ok("<h1>Server error</h1>", MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
        }
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/{file}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFiles(final FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {
        List<FormDataBodyPart> bodyParts = multiPart.getFields("dataset");

        StringBuffer fileDetails = new StringBuffer("");

        /* Save multiple files */
        for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts.size(); i++) {
            BodyPartEntity bodyPartEntity = (BodyPartEntity) bodyParts.get(i).getEntity();
            String fileName = bodyParts.get(i).getContentDisposition().getFileName();
            saveToFile(bodyPartEntity.getInputStream(), "/.../" + fileName);
            fileDetails.append(" File saved to /.../" + fileName);
        }

        System.out.println(fileDetails);

        return Response.ok(fileDetails.toString()).build();
    }

    private static String getFileBytes(String path) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = Files.toByteArray(new File(path));
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private static void saveToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {
        try {
            OutputStream out = null;
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that You have configured your endpoint to accept `multipart/form-data` but while uploading `content-type` of request is set as `text/csv`. The `content-type` of request should be set as `multipart/form-data`.

If you are using POSTMAN to test your API, there is an option `form-data` where you can pass either a text or File. Other REST clients should also have similar options or you can manually set the content type.

Comment: I am testing the API through a dead simple html form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`